# parse error при загрузке страницы

Tags: php, mysql

Ошибка:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in F:\xampp\htdocs\Основы баз данных\menu.php on line 74

Код самой строки:

```
<h4><a class='item_add' href='#'>Добавить в корзину</a></h4><span class='item_price'>'.$dish['count'].'Руб.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Вместо `'.$dish['count'].'` надо `".$dish['count']."`